# Redirecting to the installed mobile app or App store link using PHP

Tags: php, android, mobile

I have the below requirement to be executed in PHP.

I have a web page which should open the android mobile app if it's installed in the mobile.
If the app is not installed in the mobile, then it should open the app store page of the same app.

I have both the links.

Example

**appURL:** myapp://myhost?param=1

**StoreURL:** https://play.google.com/

I would be thankful if someone can help me in matching  this requirement by using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to achieve what you want, `php` cannot check if the app is installed or not. The best way is to send users to the **Play Store Link** and, if the app is installed, they can can simply tap `open` , otherwise they'll have the option to install it.